# creating a regular expression to parse a file - Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a log file I wanted to parse in the following format:

```
225:org.powertac.common.Competition::0::new::game-0
287:org.powertac.common.Competition::0::withSimulationBaseTime::1255132800000
288:org.powertac.common.Competition::0::withTimezoneOffset::-6
288:org.powertac.common.Competition::0::withLatitude::45
289:org.powertac.common.Competition::0::withBootstrapTimeslotCount::336
289:org.powertac.common.Competition::0::withBootstrapDiscardedTimeslots::24
290:org.powertac.common.Competition::0::withMinimumTimeslotCount::1400
290:org.powertac.common.Competition::0::withExpectedTimeslotCount::1440
291:org.powertac.common.Competition::0::withTimeslotLength::60
291:org.powertac.common.Competition::0::withSimulationRate::720
292:org.powertac.common.Competition::0::withTimeslotsOpen::24
292:org.powertac.common.Competition::0::withDeactivateTimeslotsAhead::1
300:org.powertac.du.DefaultBrokerService$LocalBroker::1::new::default broker
300:org.powertac.du.DefaultBrokerService$LocalBroker::1::setLocal::true
2074:org.powertac.common.RandomSeed::2::init::CompetitionControlService::0::game-setup::5354386935242895562
2157:org.powertac.common.TimeService::null::setCurrentTime::2009-10-10T00:00:00.000Z
2197:org.powertac.common.RandomSeed::3::init::AccountingService::0::interest::-8975848432442556652
2206:org.powertac.common.RandomSeed::4::init::TariffMarket::0::fees::-6239716112490883981
2213:org.powertac.common.msg.BrokerAccept::null::new::1
2214:org.powertac.common.msg.BrokerAccept::null::new::1::null
2216:org.powertac.common.RandomSeed::5::init::org.powertac.du.DefaultBrokerService::0::pricing::8741252857248937781
2226:org.powertac.common.TariffSpecification::6::new::1::CONSUMPTION
2231:org.powertac.common.Rate::7::new
2231:org.powertac.common.Rate::7::withValue::-0.5
2232:org.powertac.common.Rate::7::setTariffId::6
```

the pattern is as following:
  for a new object:

```
<id>:<classname>::<order_of_execution>::<new>::<args>
```

for a method call:

```
 <id>:<classname>::<order_of_execution>::<method_name>::<args>
```

for an internal class:

```
 <id>:<classname$innerclass>::<order_of_execution>::<method_name or new>::<args>
```

for an `init` call:

```
 <id>:<classname>::<order_of_execution>::<init>::<args>
```

I wanted a regular expression that handles all the cases, and I would be able to retrieve each value as shown in the cases.
If I want to create a new object, then I would use the `Reflection` API in `Java`.
So, for example:

```
2231:org.powertac.common.Rate::7::new
```

would be parsed into "2231", "org.powertac.common.Rate", "7", "new", args = {}.
How could I come up with such regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) with capturing groups:

```
String s = "225:org.powertac.common.Competition::0::new::game-0";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^:]+):([^:]+)::([\\d]+)::([^:]+)::(.+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
  String id = m.group(1);
  String className = m.group(2);
  int orderOfExecution = Integer.valueOf(m.group(3));
  String methodNameOrNew = m.group(4);
  String[] arguments = m.group(5).split("::");
}
```

Or an easier way, using [`java.util.Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), with the delimiter set to `::?`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
scanner.useDelimiter("::?");
int id = scanner.nextInt();
String className = scanner.next();
int orderOfExecution = scanner.nextInt();
String methodNameOrNew = scanner.next();
scanner.useDelimiter("$").skip("::");
String[] arguments = scanner.next().split("::");
```

Comment: Joao, will your regex handle all the cases?

Comment: @philippe: Yes, they all follow the same pattern. You just need to interpret, for example, if group 4 is `new` then it's a new object, else, it's a method. I've added a much easier way using `Scanner` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to shove all of this into a single regex. Make one regex expression for each pattern and, for every line, match it to each regex until you find a matching pattern. Then you can parse accordingly.

Pseudocode:

```
for line in file:
    if re.match(patNew, line):
        parseNew(line)
    elif re.match(patMethod, line):
        parseMethod(line)
    ...
```

A regex to match `<id>:<classname>::<order_of_execution>::<new>::<args>` would look something like this:

```
([0-9]+):(.*?)::([0-9]+)::(new)(?:::(.*))?
```

Comment: I can determine each case, but how would I go about creating a regex for this case, for example: `<id>:<classname>::<order_of_execution>::<new>::<args>`

Comment: @philippe I've fixed a minor issue with the regex. Tested and working with regextester.com

Answer (score -1):

As the values are colon-separated and cannot contain colons themselves, there is no need for escaping or quoting, so all you need is a simple

```
(.*):(.*)::(.*)::(.*)::(.*)
```

If the args are supposed to be optional, use

```
(.*):(.*)::(.*)::([^:]*)(?:::(.*))?
```

The values are in group 1 to 5. For instance, to find out if the log-entry is a constructor call, check if group 4 equals "new".

Comment: could you give more details? I like your approach

Comment: The following colons will prevent that the first .* matches everything. This regex works fine, as you could have easily tested by yourself.

Comment: Nice trick of removing a wrong comment to make it seem like I replied with nonsense to another question, and at the same time not removing the downvote ;-)